# Sharepoint 2010 Calculated Column based on Name field

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I need to get around the restriction that prevents the use of the Name column in a calculated column.

I basically need to create a new library column (BeginsWith) which is the first three letters of the value of (Name) - eg turning "analysis_type_dim" into "ana"

This can be done from the Title column but not the Name column (via the UI).  I tried creating a looping workflow but Microsoft have disabled this in 2010 :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a new colum NameAsText and set the field with a workflow to the value of the field "name". Then you could create a new calculated colum with the formula =mid([NameAsText];1;3) and you will get the first three letters of the "name"-field.